# SonarQube - Android not working for gradle 3.0.0

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, sonarqube, kotlin

Android sonarqube worked until I updating android studio. Now it gives an error

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
com.android.build.gradle.api.ApkVariant.getCompileLibraries()Ljava/util/Collection;
```

I think this happens because gradle dependency syntax changed from '**compile**' to '**implementation**' like below in newest android version.

from

```
dependencies {
    compile ........
    compile ........
}
```

to

```
dependencies {
    implementation ........
    implementation ........
}
```

Can anyone please help me to configure sonarqube for new android version

Answer (score 14, accepted):

*Read the last part of the answer to get the latest updates*

**Original answer**

I've performed some researches:

- [here](https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-41) you can
  find the issue tracked internally by SonarQube
- [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/62688864#comment6) you
  can find the issue opened by a SonarQube developer asking Google
  about the API change. As stated by Google engineers this change is intended and an alternative API already exists. SonarQube stated they won't support android plugin 3.0.0 until the final release or at least RC version

Result:

> To continue to work you are forced to build your project with the current stable Android Studio and Android plugin v2.X.X

---

**UPDATE - 6th November 2017**

> SonarQube released the new version 2.6 which is fully compatible with the AGP (Android Gradle Plugin) 3.0.0.

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.1'
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1"
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
    }
}

apply plugin: "org.sonarqube"
```

More info in the release page [HERE](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.sonarqube/2.6)

Comment: This is not a very good answer. I would suggest accepting the answer from @Benoit

Comment: @NelsonRamirez this was the best answer when it has been written. I will updated it when SonarQube will officially support it 
 with the stable release https://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARGRADL-41?focusedCommentId=145177&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-145177

Comment: Answer updated to reflect the latest SonarQube release

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

I am gettin gthis error while running gradlew sonarqube.

Answer (score 9):

<s>You can use my solution https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scanner-gradle/pull/33</s>

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0"
        classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6-rc1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

Comment: Seems like this specific branch is not working anymore. Can you update your answer with the currently available dependency?

Comment: @BMacedo done. I updated to the latest sonarqube classpath.

Answer (score 2):

After sonarqube 2.6 was released just updating the plugin was enough for me

```
plugins {
    id "org.sonarqube" version "2.6"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Benoit answer, the official sonar scanner gradle plugin (v2.6-rc1) already supports the new gradle syntax. So, update your root gradle script to:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        google()
        maven {
            url "https://jitpack.io"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath "com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.0.0"
        classpath "com.github.SonarSource:sonar-scanner-gradle:2.6-rc1"
    }
}

apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
```

Comment: for those not wishing to use the jitpack maven, the jcenter path is this:

`classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6-rc1"`

Comment: * What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> javax/xml/bind/JAXBException

I am gettin gthis error while running gradlew sonarqube.

Answer (score -6):

Try to use lower version of gradle