# How to resolve gradle sonarqube compatibility error?

Tags: android, sonarqube, jacoco

I am working on integrating sonarqube in my native android project to generate the code coverage report using jacoco. For that I have done the following changes in my project gradle file.

**Project gradle file:**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url 'http://repo1.maven.org/maven2' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.google.com' }
        maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        google()

        //maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.4'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.0.0'
        //classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradles-plugin:2.6.1"
        //classpath 'org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6-SNAPSHOT'
          //classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6-rc1"
       // classpath "org.sonarsource.scanner.gradle:sonarqube-gradle-plugin:2.6.1"
        //classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.+'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        maven { url "https://jitpack.io" }
        maven { url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/' }
        maven { url 'https://maven.fabric.io/public' }
        mavenCentral()
        flatDir {
            dirs 'libs'
        }
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }

    }
}

//apply plugin: 'org.sonarqube'
task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And when I run the sonar build from command prompt, it is throwing error as

> Task :sonarqube
>   Missing blame information for the following files:
>     * app/src/androidTest/java/com/olam/activities/LoginActivityTest.java
>     * app/src/androidTest/java/com/olam/activities/SplashScreenTest.java
>     * app/src/androidTest/java/olam/com/project/ExampleInstrumentedTest.java
>     * app/src/androidTest/java/olam/com/project/base/AbstractTest.java
>     * app/src/androidTest/java/olam/com/project/base/Condition.java
>     * app/src/main/java/com/olam/activities/LoginActivity.java
>   This may lead to missing/broken features in SonarQube

Any suggestion or help will be thankful

Comment: try gradlew assemble --stacktrace --info --debug command onto your projects terminal, you'll get the proper reason for the exception.

Comment: take a look at this maybe it will help you: 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46525040/sonarqube-android-not-working-for-gradle-3-0-0

Comment: Hi Thank you..i follwed the link which you mentioned...and it resolved the issue

Comment: Hi actually it is not a duplicate question..i was asking for code coverage report here..earlier there was some issue with gradle so i raised that question earlier

Comment: Error message "Missing blame information" is completely unrelated to coverage.